# What's the difference between these two array creation methods?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to know if there's any difference in either the output or the object being created when these commands are run to create the object `$array`.

```
$array = ["Sagittarius", "Cancer", "Gemini", "Pisces"];

$array = array("Sagittarius", "Cancer", "Gemini", "Pisces");
```

Thanks for the feedback!!

Comment: no difference, 2nd one was original, 1st one was added later, around php 5 (or even4), but right now both are equal

Comment: Nothing. They accomplish the same goal, and one is short syntax of the other. See [this info](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-54), but the shorter syntax came later, as the previous comment mentions.

Comment: I just read somewhere, the shorter version came in PHP 5.4.

Comment: I don't think this should be a SO question. It's a simple search to do to get this info. If you really "want to know", try to search for it before asking a question here, you may find out other interesting stuff about PHP and writing code in general.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same but [] is the shortened version introduced in PHP 5.4.0.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php